# Changing BFS to DFS via LifoQueue in Python, but it won't return a solution

Tags: python-3.x

This is homework and I would appreciate suggestions/explanations as opposed to code, but I was given code that solves 8-puzzle using BFS. I was asked to adapt it to DFS. From my understanding, as long as I direct the output as a stack (or lifoqueue), that's essentially the only difference. Yet when I run the code, it takes too long to run and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
def solve_dfs(self):
    start = self.convert_to_tuple(self.board)
    pred = {}
    visited = []

    frontier = queue.LifoQueue()
    frontier.put(start)

    print("----------------------")
    print("This is the Depth-First Search analysis:")
    print()

    while frontier.qsize() > 0:
        tmp = frontier.get()

        if tmp == self.goal:
            path = []
            while tmp != start:
                path.append(pred[tmp][1])
                tmp = pred[tmp][0]
            return path[::-1]

        if tmp not in visited:
            visited.append(tmp)
            tmpboard = self.match(tmp)
            tmpboard.move_up()
            if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) != tmp:
                frontier.put(self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board))
                if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) not in pred:
                    pred[self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board)] = [tmp, 'up']

            tmpboard = self.match(tmp)
            tmpboard.move_down()
            if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) != tmp:
                frontier.put(self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board))
                if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) not in pred:
                    pred[self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board)] = [tmp, 'down']

            tmpboard = self.match(tmp)
            tmpboard.move_right()
            if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) != tmp:
                frontier.put(self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board))
                if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) not in pred:
                    pred[self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board)] = [tmp, 'right']

            tmpboard = self.match(tmp)
            tmpboard.move_left()
            if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) != tmp:
                frontier.put(self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board))
                if self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board) not in pred:
                    pred[self.convert_to_tuple(tmpboard.board)] = [tmp, 'left']

    raise Exception('There is no solution.')
```

Comment: Complete code available if needed.

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently DFS is a long program and will take far longer than BFS. The code (as far as I can tell) is actually correct. I will keep this up for others to reference.